# Problem with translating mysql command to oracle command - triggers

Tags: oracle, plsql, triggers, oraclecommand

I had trouble converting the following command to the oracle command.
I will be glad if you help!

```
Create Trigger sales_stock_reduction
On SalesMovements
After insert
as
Declare @ProductId int
Declare @Piece int
Select @ProductId=ProductId, @Piece=Piece from inserted
Update Uruns set stock=stock - @Piece  where ProductId=@ProductId
```

In this code, when sales are made, the number of stocks in the product table is reduced through the sales movement table.
I could not write this code in oracle. Wonder how to write in Oracle

Comment: please put your code in the question instead of linking the screenshot of it, as it will be easier for us to follow. Also, please add more details to your question if there are any.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can convert that like this

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER sales_stock_reduction
AFTER INSERT ON SalesMovements
FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE
  v_ProductId inserted.ProductId%type;
  v_Piece     inserted.Piece%type;
BEGIN
  BEGIN
    SELECT ProductId, Piece
      INTO v_ProductId, v_Piece
      FROM inserted;
   EXCEPTION WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN NULL;   
  END;
  
  UPDATE Uruns
     SET stock=stock - v_Piece  
   WHERE ProductId=v_ProductId;
     
END;
/
```

In *Oracle* :

- `OR REPLACE` clause is used whenever the trigger needs to be edited
- local variables might be defined as the data type of those have
  within the table
- each individual statements end with a semi-colon
- exception handling for `NO_DATA_FOUND` is added due to presuming at most one
  row returns from the current query for the `inserted` table which doesn't have
  a `WHERE` condition to restrict the result set

Comment: I understood what you wrote very well, but it says oracle inserted table does not exist. I guess the inserted command is something special to a sql server.

Comment: Thanks! @Barbaros Özhan

Comment: you're welcome @anyone Are you able to run ?

Comment: when i compiled it is show this errors; 
**ORA-01013: user requested cancellation of current operation,  **Unexpected runtime exception while delivering HashStructureHookEvent @Barbaros Özhan

Comment: that's not pertaining to the trigger, seems like you started to run a DML, and interrupted before the data have been commited @anyone

Comment: I think I might have accidentally ran a DML for the 'Uruns' table while trying to do this trigger. Is there any way to stop this? @Barbaros Özhan

Comment: Which product are you using as IDE @anyone ?

Comment: I am working on a web project  with visual studio and oracle sql developer. @Barbaros Özhan

Comment: Unfortunately I don't use that, but there should be an item on the top menu to break it up, or you can use `ALTER SYSTEM KILL SESSION '<sid, serial#>'` if you can access into sys as sysdba privilege @anyone

Comment: ok i will try thank you for your help @Barbaros  Özhan

Comment: `satis_stok_azalt` and `sales_stock_reduction` are the same triggers ? Btw, You shouldn't create an object within system or sys schemas. Does `inserted` table contain more than one row? @anyone if that's the case then add a WHERE with a suitable condition and replace `no_data_found` with `others`.

Comment: yes the two are the same trigger. I created the 'inserted' table myself and added .'urunid' and 'adet' to it. Was it wrong?

Comment: if there's only one row, then no problem @anyone